# Having problems declaring a string

Tags: c++

So, I started using C++ today, and wanted to make a small, text-based adventure, but that didn't turn out all that well.

Here's my code:

```
string answer;
string name;
string charName;
std::cout << "<Ominous voice> Hi there, what's your name?" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Enter your name:" << std::endl;
getline(cin, name);
std::cout << "<Ominous voice> " << name << "? That's an... interesting name." << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cout << "<Ominous voice> Before we start off... You need to learn the basics, so let's break the fourth wall shall we?" << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cout << "<Ominous voice> I'm here to guide you on this wonderfull adventure... for just $ 9.99." << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cout << "<Ominous voice> You can name me everything you want, since I'm a fragment of your imagination anyway... So, what about it?" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Enter a name:" << std::endl;
getline(cin, charName);
strcpy (str1,"<");
strcpy (str2,">");
strcat (str1,charName, 1);
strcat (charName,str2, charName.size();
std::cout << charName << " Well then, it seems I'm now called '" << charName << "' not sure if I like that." << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cout << "This line does not show up" << std::endl;
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. I get these messages when I start the program:

   ```
   /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
   /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:13: error: ‘str1’ was not declared in this scope
        strcpy (str1,"<");
                ^
   /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:24:13: error: ‘str2’ was not declared in this scope
        strcpy (str2,">");
                ^
   /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:26:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
        strcat (charName,str2, charName.size();
                                              ^
   ```
2. That last line, saying "This line does not show up", actually doesn't show up.

I know I'm basic and this is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but I'm a beginner.

Comment: You shouldn't use `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the lines where you use strcpy and strcat?

Comment: I wanted to achieve to put <> at the beginning and end of the user input, for instance, if you put in Jack, it would show up as <Jack>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare string str1 before using it. Decraling means

```
std::string str1;
```

In C++ the definition is e.g.

```
str1 = "heureka";
```

And the declaration has always be in front of the definition.
But you can do both in one line:

```
std::string str1 = "heureka";
```

or

```
std::string str1("heureka");
```

If you want to add "<" in front and ">" behind the characters name. You can do it as follows:

```
charName = "<" + charName + ">";
```

There is no need to create new strings for it. There is simply a + operator for strings and it is easier to use than strcpy, strcat or so.

Comment: And next this won't compile: `strcat (str1,charName, 1);`

Comment: I added code how to concatenate strings easily.

Comment: Thank you so much, my code is now working and I'm very happy with that I was able to do it without strcat (honestly, it confused me a lot), so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't declared the strings `str1` and `str2`.